# Binding an event to a non object sender Event Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to bind this event and I'm getting a

> 'No overload for AddEvent matches delegate EventHandler'

Error. If I change the type of `sender` to `object` then it works but I need it to be `Linkbutton` for the content of the method.  Is there a way to typecast? Or another solution?

```
LinkButton addLink = new LinkButton();
addLink.Click += AddEvent;


protected void AddEvent(LinkButton sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // content
}
```

Comment: Normally the sender is received as an object. You cant change the signature of the method.

All that you need to do is test if the sender is the type that you need.

This should do the work.

    var _linkbutton= sender as LinkButton;
    if (_linkbutton != null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EventHandler`'s first parameter should be of type `object` then use one of the following ways:

```
protected void AddEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Cast to LinkButton
    var linkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
    //Or use is keyword like below
    if (sender is LinkButton)
    {

    }
    //Or use as keyword
    LinkButton linkButton = sender as LinkButton;
    if (linkButton != null)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way IMO. first line should be "var oSend = (LinkButton)sender;" .... then operate on oSend... (or whatever you name it)... you can even check type to make sure it's a LinkButton before casting if you want to add that logic (probably a good idea).

Comment: OP already wrote *If I change the type of sender to object then it works* in the question, so this "answer" doesn't add anything to the subject.

Comment: @IvanStoev it's just missing what I wrote in there.. he can edit it - it's not wrong, it just needs an addition.. This is the correct way to handle it - he just needs the casting.

Comment: Creating the oSend variable seems to remove all compilation errors.  Thanks!

Comment: @Aaron Sure. But it wasn't at the time I wrote the previous comment, hence the criticism :) Also why posting initially meaningless answer to duplicate (basic) question at all? Post a comment an vote/dupe hammer it and move on (as Servy did).

Comment: @IvanStoev touche, touche :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
LinkButton addLink = new LinkButton();


addLink.Click += (x, y) => AddEvent((LinkButton)x, y);


protected void AddEvent(LinkButton sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: I voted up because it works!   Rather there is no compilation error.   What does that do btw? What is the x and y?

Comment: Thanks! It's registering a lambda to the event handler so x maps to object (that's why a cast is needed) and y maps to EventArgs. Can you also mark right if it's the correct answer?

Comment: Actually it doesn't quite work.  The x cannot be converted from object to Linkbutton.

Comment: You need to cast it (I made an edit to the original version)... This is what you will have to do if you use @s-akbari answer.